# If $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ show there are just two equivalence relations on $X$ with $1\sim 2$ and $2 \sim3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> If $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, then if $1 \sim 2$ and $2 \sim 3$ show that there are just two possibilities for the relation $\sim$ and describe both relations.

This was a bonus question assigned on our last test in proofs. We were studying sets and equivalence relations in particular.  As it is a proofs class, there must be proof statements and such included. I wasn't able to even begin to figure this question out though.

Comment: Hint: an equivalence relation can be defined by specifying the equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0):

Either everything is related to everything, or the only thing 4 is related to is itself.

Comment: I see.. 
so .. S`={1,2,3} and S"={4}
or S`={1,2,3,4}

but in a formal proof how would go about actually SHOWING this, I mean a partitioned diagram is one thing but a full proof is another don't you think?

Comment: Certainly, what I gave was nothing close to a proof.  What is given is that 1 ~ 2 and 2 ~ 3 so by transitivity 1 ~ 3 and by symmetry and reflexivity, you get that for every two elements of {1,2,3} the relationship holds.  Now if any of these relates to 4, then again by transitivity, symmetry, and reflexivity, the relationship will hold between every two elements of {1,2,3,4} and this characterizes the relationship.  On the other hand, if the relationship does not hold between 4 and any elements of {1,2,3}, then by reflexivity 4 ~ 4, and this characterizes this other possible relationship.

Comment: Of course, this also isn't a full-blown "from the axioms" proof either.  But whatever is the level of proof you require, this blue-print should guide you through it.